# Hibernate audit columns in each table without repeating them in each <class> definition?

Tags: hibernate

When using hibernate is it possible to specify that certain columns (including id, audit columns, etc) are present in an abstract base class? This seems like a fairly common practice. Especially for auditing?

However, I need to have this base class just specify the column names and property/method names for just the audit columns. While the Integer id column exists in the abstract base class, I need to define the id element in hibernate in the concrete class, as each concrete class will use a different sequence.

I originally started looking for a way to simply "include" an hbm file in another hbm file and define the audit columns in a single place, but didn't find a solution for that. Then I started looking at using the class with abstract=true, but it seems that those classes still need an id, which doesn't really work in my situation.

Seems that @MappedSuperClass would work in the annotation world, but I have not been able to find a solution when using .hbm.xml files?

Can someone please provide an example of how I might be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't seem to support mapped superclass in XML, so you may try to simulate it using `abstract` and `union-subclass` as described in [this article](http://gardiary.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/hibernate-superclass-interface-inheritance-mapping/). It's pretty cumbersome,though.