# Alternatives to No-Args Constructor

Tags: java, hibernate

I understand that when Hibernate loads one of my entities from the database, it is necessary for it to construct a new instance of the object using something *similar* to `Class.newInstance()`.

Thus, Hibernate will complain when it attempts to serialize classes that do not expose a no-args constructor:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.acme.Person
```

Lets assume that `com.acme.Person` is a class from an external third-party library. This means I cannot alter the definition of the class, and am unable to add the default constructor as requested.

What are my alternatives?

From a conceptual point-of-view, it'd be great if I could provide Hibernate with a factory, something like:

```
public class PersonFactory implements Factory<Person> {
    public Person create() {
        // ctor takes firstName, lastName
        return new Person(null, null);
    }
}
```

Using this instance of `Person`, Hibernate will then be able to use the standard reflection techniques to re-set the member variables (in this case `firstName` and `lastName`) with the values loaded from the database.

---

I have found commentary about using a custom `UserType` to handle the serialization / deserialization of this type. This seems like complete overkill, there is no custom serialization logic per-se, and I have no interest in writing custom `nullSafeSet` / `nullSafeGet`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `org.hibernate.Interceptor`.

This interface has a method [`instantiate()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#instantiate(java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.EntityMode,%20java.io.Serializable)) which Hibernate then uses to create instances of entities.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is to have a look at the `org.hibernate.tuple` package.

You can create a custom entity `org.hibernate.tuple.Tuplizer` and a custom `org.hibernate.tuple.Instantiator`. The Tuplizer will be a factory for instances of your Instantiator and you can register it to the `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` that creates the session factory with something like:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
...
conf.getEntityTuplizerFactory().registerDefaultTuplizerClass(EntityMode.POJO, MyPojoEntityTuplizer.class);
...
SessionFactory sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
```

The Instantiator can be something like this:

```
public class FactoryBasedPojoEntityInstantiator implements Instantiator {

    private Class<?> entityClass;

    public Bo2PojoEntityInstantiator(PersistentClass persistentClass) {
        this.entityClass = persistentClass.getMappedClass();
    }


    public Object instantiate(Serializable id) {
        return Factory.create(entityClass);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate (and JPA, because it requires no-arg constructors in the specification) is a bit limited when it comes to customization of creation of entity instances. Hopefully, things will change in subsequent versions of Hibernate and JPA standard.

You can use Hibernate interceptors or instantiators for this (as already pointed out in other answers). Keep in mind though that lazy loading of `Person` instances will not work then, because Hibernate will not be able to create proxies for them.

The solution that does not involve changing any of instantiation mechanisms is to create a subclass of `Person` which provides the no-arg constructor:

```
public class PersonEntity extends Person {
   public PersonEntity() {
      super(null, null);
   }
}
```

Since `Person` is a class from an external library, then you must be using xml to map it. If you use JPA xml, then just indicate that it is `mapped-superclass`. If you use `hbm.xml`, then (interestingly) things are a bit more complicated, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6964662/4754790) for more details.